# Mongoose query - groupBy category and get last 4 items of each category

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am struggling in Writing that **fetches 4 Products of each category**. What I have done is

```
 exports.recentproducts = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
     const doc = await Product.aggregate([
    { $sort: { date: -1 } },
    {
      $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: {
          $mergeObjects: [{ $arrayElemAt: ['$products', 0] }, '$$ROOT'],
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {    
        _id: '$productCategory',
        products: { $push: '$$ROOT' },
      },
    },

    {
      $project: {
        // pagination for products
        products: {
          $slice: ['$products', 4],
        },
        _id: 1,
       
      },
    },
    {
       $lookup: {
           from: 'Shop',
           localField: 'shopId',
           foreignField: '_id',
           as: 'shop',
     },
    },
  ]);
```

Document Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
   var ProductSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        require: [true, 'Product must have a Title!'],
      },
      productCategory: {
        type: String,
        require: [true, 'Product must have a Category!'],
      },
      shopId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Shop',
        require: [true, 'Product must have a Shop!'],
      },
    });
    
    var Product = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
    module.exports = Product;
```

expected result---

```
result= [
    {
        productCategory: "Graphics",
        products:[//4 products object here
           {
               must populate shop data
           }
       ]
    },
    {
        productCategory: "3d",
        products:[//4 products object here]
    },
       //there are seven categories I have like that
  ]
```

> The Code i have done is working fine but it has two problems
> It does not populate shopId from Shop Model even through I have tried lookup
> It does not sort products in descending order(does not sort by date)

Comment: YOu need to show us the documents and expected result

Comment: I have added more details can you please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few fixes in your implemented query,

- `$sort` stage as it is,
- `$group` stage as it is and moves to the second stage
- `$project` stage as it is and move to third stage
- `$lookup` with shop collection, pass `products.shopId` as `localField`
- `$project` for merge shop object in `products` array
- `$map` to iterate loop of `products` array
- `$filter` to iterate loop of shop array return matching product
- `$arrayElemAt` to get first element from above filtered result
- `$mergeOjects` to merge current object with filtered `shop` object

```
const doc = await Product.aggregate([
  { $sort: { date: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$productCategory",
      products: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      products: { $slice: ["$products", 4] }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Shop",
      localField: "products.shopId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "shop"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      products: {
        $map: {
          input: "$products",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                shop: {
                  $arrayElemAt: [
                    {
                      $filter: {
                        input: "$shop",
                        as: "s",
                        cond: { $eq: ["$$s._id", "$$this.shopId"] }
                      }
                    },
                    0
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mqAE_izHaL7)

Answer (score 1):

Query

- in MongoDB 5 we can use `$setWindowFields` and `$rank`
- partition by `productCategory` and sort by date descending
- keep only `rank <= 4` (4 latest products)
- lookup to get the shop information
- group by category and push all the information of product and shop

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=68864134-m)

```js
Product.aggregate(
[{$setWindowFields:
  {partitionBy:"$productCategory",
   sortBy:{date:-1},
   output:{rank:{$rank:{}}}}},
 {$match:{rank:{$lte:4}}},
 {$lookup:
  {from:"Shop",
   localField:"shopId",
   foreignField:"_id",
   as:"shop"}},
 {$set:{shop:{$first:"$shop"}}},
 {$group:{_id:"$productCategory", products:{$push:"$$ROOT"}}}])
```

Comment: This code is giving an error.    Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$setWindowFields

Comment: it needs mongodb 5, that why i said in mongodb 5 we can do it like that, you have older version i guess.